# Chaning image-button to text-button using Devise login

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have it currently so someone can click on the login button and when somebody signs in it changes that to logout. How would I be able to make it so it sets the button as the user's avatar that they have uploaded (or default one) when they login and then when they logout it changes back to "sign in"?

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="button-login">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>
      <%= link_to "Logout", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %>
    <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %>
    <% end %>
    </button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <p>
      <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <%= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path, :class => 'navbar-link' %> 
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path %> 
      <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: So what's your code?

Comment: Edited my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do this by using a block:

```
<%= link_to destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete do %>
  <%= image_tag("avatar.jpg", :alt => "user avatar image") %>
<% end %>
```